# CEFSHARP - ChromiumWebBrowser on get table row cell values

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, cefsharp

I solved most of my problems, but I couldn't find a solution for one of them.
Previously, I was using Windows WebBrowser and getting a table result on a query screen in a dealer panel. Like this;

```
foreach (HtmlElement htmlobj in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("Table"))
 {
     if (htmlobj.GetAttribute("className") == "table table-striped")
     {
          foreach (HtmlElement tr in htmlobj.GetElementsByTagName("tbody"))
          {
               foreach (HtmlElement td in tr.Children)
              {
                    string s0 =  td.Children[0].InnerText;
                    string s1 =  td.Children[1].InnerText;
               }
          }
     }
}
```

How can I do this with ChromiumWebBrowser?

Thanks a lot for helps... ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved in CefSharp using [`EvaluateScriptAsync`](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#2-how-do-you-call-a-javascript-method-that-returns-a-result), by executing JavaScript to find the table's `td` elements and return them as an array, which C# will receive as a `List<object>`

If you didn't already know, you have to usually wait until the page's `MainFrame` has loaded before executing any JavaScript, which you could implement like:

```cs
//...
ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://example.com"); // <- Your URL there

browser.FrameLoadEnd += (sender, args) =>
{
  // Wait for the MainFrame to finish loading
  if(args.Frame.IsMain)
      GetTable(); // method to call that executes JavaScript, etc
}
```

[More information about when you can start executing JavaScript.](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#when-can-i-start-executing-javascript)

Now, this is the code I made for `EvaluateScriptAsync` to return the `td`'s `innerText` into C#:

```cs
// assuming "browser" is the ChromiumWebBrowser and you're ready to start executing JavaScript (see above code)
private void GetTable ()
{
    const string script = @"(function(){
        let table = document.querySelector('table.table.table-striped'); // <table class='table table-striped'>
        let td = table.getElementsByTagName('td');
        return [ td[0].innerText, td[1].innerText ];
    })();";

    browser.GetMainFrame().EvaluateScriptAsync(script).ContinueWith(x =>
    {
        var response = x.Result;

        if (response.Success && response.Result != null)
        {
            // We cast values as CefSharp wouldn't know what to expect
            List<object> jsResult = (List<object>)response.Result;

            string s1 = (string)jsResult[0]; // td[0].innerText
            string s2 = (string)jsResult[1]; // td[1].innerText

            Console.WriteLine("s1: " + s1);
            Console.WriteLine("s2: " + s2);
            // In my example HTML page, it will output:
            // s1: This is 1st
            // s2: This is 2nd
        }
    });
}
```

I made this HTML example to test it on, as you didn't provide any:

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>One</th>
        <th>Two</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>This is 1st</td>
        <td>This is 2nd</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Excellent Answer!

Comment: I'll will point of that if you change `return [ td[0].innerText, td[1].innerText ]` to `return { Text1 : td[0].innerText, Text2 :td[1].innerText };` you can use `dynamic` in `c#` to access the response in a slightly nicer way.

Comment: amaitland, Thanks for answer!